# Compare all files of a folder pairwise

Tags: bash

Input:

z2042 
z0138 
z0189 
z2294

Hello,

I want to compare all files in a folder with each other to see, if they are different.
So like: z2042 with z0138, z0138 with z0189, z0189 with z2042 and so on...

I know how to compare all files with a single file:

`for i in ./z*; do diff -q "$i" z2294; done`

But i dont know how to compare all files with all.
I tried it with another for loop for with the Variable "x" instead of z2294, but it didnt work :/

Thx for help

Comment: Do you want to compare only sequential pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
z_files="./z*"
for i in $z_files; do
  for j in $z_files; do
    if [ "$i" \> "$j" ]; then
      diff -q "$i" "$j"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: This will compare each pair twice. That is, it'll run `diff -q z2042 z0138` and also `diff -q z0138 z2042`. You could change the condition to`if [ "$i" \> "$j" ]; then` to solve this. Note that the `>` operator must be quoted or escaped in a `[ ]` test; it would *not* be quoted or escaped in a `[[ ]]` conditional expression.

Comment: Thanks that worked!
But I tried to use this also for the opposite, so that the script should look if they are the same. I replaced '-q' with '-s' but that just bombed me with I think all the lines ine the files which are the same or sth like that. Can I fix this? I just want an Output like "./z1234 and ./2134 are the same"

Comment: @Argaros You could check the return code of `diff` and handle it according to your needs.  Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233395/if-and-else-statement-using-diff-q)

Comment: Yep, iIgot it. Thx man :D